# How to fix pip for Python 3.5 not compiling extensions on Windows x64

Tags: python, pip

There are many questions on here about problems with pip installing Python extensions which require C++ compilation. However many of these solutions are out of data as of Python 3.5.

Mostly these problems revolve around the missing vcvarsall.bat problem that comes with not installing Microsoft Visual Studio or not installing the right version.

Having dealt with this issue I am now faced with a value error when I try to install these module through pip.

Can anyone provide a canonical method to get a fresh install of Python 3.5 x64 on a fresh install of Windows (Windows 7 x64 in my case) to be able to correctly install modules through pip that require compilation?

For reference here is the error I am currently getting while attempting to install matplotlib (note the error is being caused by pip attempting to update numpy as it is required by matplotlib)

```
  vc_env = query_vcvarsall(VERSION, plat_spec)
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\setuptools\msvc9_support.py", line 52,
in query_vcvarsall
    return unpatched['query_vcvarsall'](version, *args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Python34\lib\distutils\msvc9compiler.py", line 287, in query_vcvarsall
    raise ValueError(str(list(result.keys())))
ValueError: ['path']
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For 3.5 you need Visual C++ 14.0.

Download the [**Community edition**](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/products/vs-2015-product-editions.aspx).

cl.exe will be in:

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\bin
```

Comment: What is it I am supposed to do with cl.exe? It dosn't seem to be mentioned in the error message

Comment: @axevalley without vc 14 you will not be able to built extensions for python 3.5. cl.exe is a compiler. i just showed you the path to it. You may need to include the path in windows path to build extensions, ones you download the correct compiler for python 3.5.

Comment: I'm not entirely sure what has happened. I started getting an error message reading: 'Fatal error: Unable to create process using '"'''. After googling this I found a post saying to runn the command as 'python -m pip' instead of just 'pip'. When I do this everything works fine. So problem solved. Thank you for your input @LetzerWille

Answer (score 0):

Installing NumPy and matplotlib with precompiled .whl binaries would avoid this problem entirely.

download: **numpy-1.10.1+mkl-cp35-none-win_amd64.whl**
from: [lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#numpy](http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#numpy)

and

download: **matplotlib-1.5.0rc3-cp35-none-win_amd64.whl**
from [lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#matplotlib](http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#matplotlib)

Installation:

```
python -m pip install numpy-1.10.1+mkl-cp35-none-win_amd64.whl

python -m pip install matplotlib-1.5.0rc3-cp35-none-win_amd64.whl
```

Answer (score 0):

another thing I just discovered is that you can do

```
pip install --only-binary matplotlib
```

this will avoid having to install 4GB+ of C++ Build Tools or requiring admin rights, and I think it fetches the latest binary available for matplotlib